# How can I bind the same dependency to many dependents in Ninject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Let's I have three interfaces: `IFoo`, `IBar`, `IBaz`. I also have the classes `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` that are the respective implementations.

In the implementations, each depends on the interface `IContainer`. So for the `Foo` (and similarly for `Bar` and `Baz`) the implementation might read:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IDependency Dependency;

    public Foo(IDependency dependency)
    {
           Dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("I'm using {0}", Dependency.Name);
    }
}
```

Let's furthermore say I have a class `Container` which happens to contain instances of the `IFoo`, `IBar` and `IBaz`:

```
class Container : IContainer
{
    private readonly IFoo _Foo;
    private readonly IBar _Bar;
    private readonly IBaz _Baz;

    public Container(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IBaz baz)
    {
        _Foo = foo;
        _Bar = bar;
        _Baz = baz;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, I would like the implementation class `Container` to bind against `IContainer` with the constraint that the `IDependency` that gets injected into `IFoo`, `IBar`, and `IBaz` be the same for all three. In the manual way, I might implement it as:

```
IDependency dependency = new Dependency();
IFoo foo = new Foo(dependency);
IBar bar = new Bar(dependency);
IBaz baz = new Baz(dependency);
IContainer container = new Container(foo, bar, baz);
```

How can I achieve this within Ninject?

**Note: I am not asking how to do nested dependencies. My question is how I can guarantee that a given dependency is the same among a collection of objects within a materialized service.**

To be extremely explicit, I understand that Ninject in it's standard form will generate code that is equivalent to the following:

```
IContainer container = new Container(new Foo(new Dependency()), new Bar(new Dependency()), new Baz(new Dependency()));
```

I would *not* like that behavior. I cannot have the `Dependency` created as a singleton either. Specifically, this means that if I have multiple requests to `GetService<IContainer>`, the Ninject calls should be semantically equivalent to the following manual injection:

```
var dep1 = new Dependency();
var container1 = new IContainer(new Foo(dep1), new Bar(dep1), new Baz(dep1));

var dep2 = new Dependency();
var container2 = new IContainer(new Foo(dep2), new Bar(dep2), new Baz(dep2));
```

Comment: this should be fairly simple. look at how you bind things. hope this helps http://stefanoricciardi.com/2011/01/21/ninject-mini-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: @DarthVader: Please see the comment I left on Konstantin's answer.

Comment: you dont need poor man's DI, which is what u last code does. To keep it short, yes, you get the same instance of dependency for Foo, Bar and Baz. To understand better of this concepts, look at life time and scope of DI. for example: per request, per thread , singleton etc.

Comment: i dont think you need anything ToConstant code, or anything complicated. perhaps, best thing for your to do is test, debug it. you will be fine. with basic binding which is usually instance per request.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ToConstant` method to specify exact instance to bind to. If there is an opportunity you can use `Unbind` to rebind to another instance:

```
        IKernel nKernel = new StandardKernel();

        nKernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
        nKernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
        nKernel.Bind<IBaz>().To<Baz>();
        nKernel.Bind<IContainer>().To<Container>();

        nKernel.Bind<IDependency>().ToConstant(new Dependency());            

        Container c = nKernel.Get<Container>();
        //utilize the container...

        nKernel.Unbind<IDependency>();
        nKernel.Bind<IDependency>().ToConstant(new Dependency());

        c = nKernel.Get<Container>();
        //utilize the container...
```

Comment: Will this guarantee the `Dependency` generated is exactly the same for `IFoo`, `IBar` and `IBaz` within the `IContainer`? That is my primary concern. You have not answered that question.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Your Foo, Bar, Baz will get three different objects of type Dependency

Comment: I do not want that. As my question states and as my edit reflects, I want to know if it is possible to have the same `Dependency` being bound to `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` dependencies in the `Container`.

Comment: @MikeBantegui please see my edits...but it assumes, that the object exists at the moment of binding

Comment: @MikeBantegui Did `ToConstant` do the trick? Or I'm still missing something?

Comment: I have to do testing, I will report my findings shortly.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

How about this?

```
kernel.Bind<IContainer>().ToMethod(context =>
            {
                IDependency dependency = new Dep();
                IFoo foo = new Foo(dependency);
                IBar bar = new Bar(dependency);
                IBaz baz = new Baz(dependency);
                return new Container(foo, bar, baz);
            });
```

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid `InSingletonScope`? The object I'm dealing with performs extremely poorly when it's used as a singleton.

Comment: @MikeBantegui I think so, I've updated my answer with an idea.

Comment: Isn't that still technically a singleton? It almost seems like the appropriate thing would be to make the call as: `.ToMeth(context => new Dep())`.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Then you wouldn't be getting the same instance to each Foo, Bar, and Baz...

Comment: The problem is, I need it to be the same for each `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` in a `Container,` but for it to be distinct among many `Container`s.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Ah, updated my answer maybe that gets us a bit closer?

Comment: That's about 99% of what I want. Is there any way I can do so without having to specify the dependency chain manually? I'm trying avoid forcing myself into doing manual injection.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Yeah I agree all the manual dependency work is not ideal, I'll have a think and see if I can come up with something else

Comment: @MikeBantegui I've added another answer, I think we're pretty darn close now

Answer (score 1):

Here's another attempt:

```
public class Container : IContainer
{
    private IFoo _foo;
    private IBar _bar;
    private IBaz _baz;


    public Container(IContainerDependencies dependencies)
    {
        _foo = dependencies.Foo;
        _bar = dependencies.Bar;
        _baz = dependencies.Baz;
    }
}

public class ContainerDependencies : IContainerDependencies
{
    public ContainerDependencies(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IBaz baz)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        Bar = bar;
        Baz = baz;
    }

    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }
    public IBaz Baz { get; set; }
}

public interface IContainerDependencies
{
    IFoo Foo { get; set; }
    IBar Bar { get; set; }
    IBaz Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
kernel.Bind<IBaz>().To<Baz>();
kernel.Bind<IContainerDependencies>().ToMethod(context =>
    {
        context.Kernel.Unbind<IDependency>();
        context.Kernel.Bind<IDependency>().ToConstant(new Dep());
        return context.Kernel.Get<ContainerDependencies>();
    });
 kernel.Bind<IContainer>().To<Container>();
```

Comment: While creating the second instanse of the container you would probable get the following exception: *Error activating IDependency: More than one matching bindings are available.*

Comment: This will actually break other bindings which depend on the `IDependency`. Better would be to remove all current bindings, create the new binding, resolve instance, then add back in the previous bindings. Seems a bit suboptimal though.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Sometimes the simplest solution is just hard coding what you need and not worrying about having a "generic" or "dynamic" solution for your 1 off cases. I'm not sure the juice here is worth the squeeze at this point.